# Efficiently appending data to a variable using Matlab's C API

Tags: matlab

I have a C program which repeatedly executes an algorithm and outputs its intermediate result after each iteration. The data will be processed using Matlab R2019a.

I'm using the [C Matrix API](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cc-mx-matrix-library.html) to create .MAT files, and I can write a matrix to the .MAT file:

```c
  MATFile *m = matOpen("matlab.MAT", "w");
  mxArray *a = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 1, mxREAL);
  *mxGetPr(a) = nxm;
  matPutVariable(m, "nxm", a);
  mxDestroyArray(a);
  matClose(m);
```

However, the documentation for `[maxPutVariable](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/matputvariable.html)` states that if I use the same variable name twice, the second will overwrite the first.

I do not want to store in memory all of my intermediate values. Perhaps I could read in the matrix, extend it to include a new value, and write it out again.

Is there a decent way to do this using the C API, or should I just write Matlab code to parse a different output format?

Comment: The MAT file format is pretty efficient for numeric array data. Just how large are your intermediate results? Is I/O performance critical here? And does your downstream Matlab process need to process some of the results while your C program is still running, or can it wait until the C program is finished and process them all at once?

Comment: (I'm provisionally thinking that you'd put each intermediate result into a different `nxmNNNN` variable where `NNNN` is your loop index or whatever, and then read that into Matlab and have it just `cat()` all the `nxmNNN` variables; that'd be just a few lines of code.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save multiple named variables in a single MAT-file. And when you add a new variable to a MAT-file, it's appended to the end of the file, so that's not bad on I/O even if your existing file is relatively large. So what I'd do is have each loop iteration of your C program store its output into a new named `nxm<NNN>` variable in the MAT-file, and then have your Matlab program read the file and concatenate them all together.

In your C code:

```
MATFILE *m = matOpen("matlab.mat", "w");
[...]
char var_name[1024];
for (i = 0; i < n_iterations; i++) {
  [... do work to produce nxm ...]
  mxArray *a = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 1, mxREAL);
  *mxGetPr(a) = nxm;
  sprintf(var_name, "nxm%d", i);
  matPutVariable(m, var_name, a);
  mxDestroyArray(a);
}
matClose(m);
```

Then on the Matlab side after that's all done:

```
s = load('matlab.mat');
c = struct2cell(s);
all_data = cat(1, c{:});
```

You could also write your code so that each pass reads in the previous pass's output, extends the array, and writes it back to the same named variable. But that would be a lot more coding in C, and (I think) would perform less well if your intermediate results were large, instead of these single numbers.

For that matter, since it looks like you're working with a small data set - `nxm` is a scalar `double` - you could just `fprintf("%d\n", nxm)` your nxm values to a text file with a single number on each line, and then read it in to Matlab using `fscanf` or `str2double`.

Comment: Thanks. Suppose I have multiple arrays in the same file, like `nxm` and `nym`. Can I concatenate all the `nxm_i` and `nym_j` this way?

Comment: Yup. Have your Matlab code do `s = load(...); vars = fieldnames(s);` to get a list of all the variables, and then use `regexp` or `startsWith` to detect which of the variables stored in the file match those patterns and should be concatenated by group into distinct output variables.

Comment: Or if you don't even know ahead of time what all names of variables might be in the file, use `target_var = regexprep(vars, '_.*')` to map the file var names to target code var names, call `unique(target_var)` to get a list of the resulting "condensed" variables, and use `ismember(target_var, vars)` to decide which input variables from the file should be concatenated to produce each condensed output variable.